# How to set screen resolution in Windows when no monitor is connected?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution

I have a Windows computer without a monitor that I frequently remote into.  The screen resolution is way too small because the graphics card doesn't know what resolutions to recommend.  I tried creating a custom resolution in the Nvidia settings but it says that the resolution is not supported by the display, which doesn't exist.

Any ideas or recommendations.  I just need to set the resolution to something that is readable from my laptop when I remote in.

Edit: I am using Chrome Remote Desktop as Windows Remote Desktop is not supported by my Windows Home Edition.

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to set the screen resolution on the machine. You set the resolution in your remoting application of choice. In the standard MSTSC application it is done here:

[image]

Comment: I am actually using Chrome Remote Desktop.  My Windows Home Edition does not support sharing the desktop through Microsoft Remote Desktop.  I should have mentioned this.